# Drawing method flow

Tags: java, methods, data-structures, structure

I have tried to draw noDuplicate method for array, but I couldn't completed it. Ay help with that:

```
public void noDups(){

    int size = elementsSize - 1;
    long duplicated = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        duplicated = longArray[i];

        for (int j = i+1; j <= size; j++) {
            if(longArray[j] == duplicated){

                for (int k = j; k < size; k++) {
                    longArray[k] = longArray[k+1];
                }
                elementsSize--;
                j--;
                size--;
                System.out.println("Duplicated Deleted using noDups " + duplicated);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please see attached file for drawing ref.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you create a set and put all your element into it.It will retain only unique value.